# Return z coordinate when x and y coordinates given as arguments in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been searching the documentation of matplotlib for a very long time now and I can't find a function that can do this for me. I have plotted a matrix and used bicubic interpolation to make it into a smooth graph, and I would like to be able to find the z coordinate of a point when I give the x and y coordinates. For example:
`plt.some_function(1.5, 2)`
Where 1.5 is the x coordinate and 2 is the y coordinate, would produce the result:
`3`
Where 3 is the z coordinate of that point.

Comment: I admit I am not familiar with matplotlib, but wouldn't you be able to create your own metjod that returns the evaluated for z?

Comment: Why do you need matplotlib to give you back the data that you handed to it?  Why not pull the data from the data you fed into the plot function?